# sqldeveloper 4.1.1 new connection no access tab

Tags: ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

sqldeveloper 4.1.1 new connection "Access" tab missing. I have windows 8.1 64bit. I tried 32bit 64bit office. I tried Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included, Windows 32-bit/64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle sqldeveloper starting version 4.1 require java 8 which remove jdbc-odbc bridge necessary for the program to connect Microsoft access database. sqldeveloper 4.0 with java 7 works.
reference:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3758769
https://community.oracle.com/thread/3726855

Answer (score -1):

From access to link to a server database you use the external data tab, and from that tab choose ODBC database.

So there never was some “new” connection button or tab, but only that of using the ODBC connection manager.

Comment: OP is asking for the "Access" tab connection that were in SQL Developer, which established a JDBC-ODBC connection bridge in order to connect from SQL Developer to a Access database. JDBC-ODBC connection bridge its no longer supported since Java 8, which is the Java version required for SQL Developer 4.1.x and up